# How to prevent or disable selections in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am trying to disable row selection in DataGridView in winforms. I used below code and its working as expected other than 1st row.

```
protected override void OnRowValidating(DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

For 1st row, this method is not called and I am able to select the row.
Can anyone have a solution for this issue

I would like to disable all kind of selections (Row, column or cell selection).
I cannot use `IsEnabled = false` because horizontal/vertical scrolling need to be retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to disable all kind of selections (Row, column or cell
> selection). I cannot use `Enabled = false` because horizontal/vertical
> scrolling need to be retained.

To completely disable any selection in a DataGridView, you can set `CurrentCell = null` when a user changes Row or Cell, interacting with the Control.
This of course also disables any editing of the Cells.
It's like an *enforced* read-only mode; the default `ReadOnly` Property doesn't prevent a visible selection.

The grid can scroll and also clicking the Columns' headers allows to order the data.

Setting `CurrentCell = null` prevents all selections except when dragging the Mouse Pointer, which highlight Rows.
This happens only when `MultiSelect = true`, when set to `false`, no selection can be performed dragging the Mouse.

**Suggested edit 1** (no selection allowed, no edit allowed, sorting allowed):

- Added a `SelectionEnabled` public (modify as required) Property so you can toggle this state.
- `OnSelectionChanged` is overridden to apply the state (you must call `base` before you set `CurrentCell = null`).

```
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView {

    private bool m_SelectionEnabled = true;
    private bool multiSelectCachedState = false;

    public DataGridViewEx() { }

    public bool SelectionEnabled { 
        get => m_SelectionEnabled;
        set {
            if (m_SelectionEnabled != value) {
                m_SelectionEnabled = value;
                if (!m_SelectionEnabled) {
                    multiSelectCachedState = MultiSelect;
                    MultiSelect = false;
                    ClearSelection();
                }
                else {
                    MultiSelect = multiSelectCachedState;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        multiSelectCachedState = MultiSelect;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        // Prevents Cell edit
        if (!m_SelectionEnabled) CurrentCell = null;
    }
}
```

**Suggested edit 2** (no selection allowed, Cell edit allowed, sorting allowed):

As you can see in the [.Net Source Code about CurrentCell](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2176), setting this property to `null` causes a call to `ClearSelection()`, but based on some conditions.

Calling `ClearSelection()` directly, causes a call to [SetSelectedCellCore()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,27631) (suspends bulk paint, clears the selection and invalidates Columns and Rows in the end), which doesn't prevent editing.

The code is, give or take, the same:

```
public bool SelectionEnabled { 
    get => m_SelectionEnabled;
    set {
        if (m_SelectionEnabled != value) {
            m_SelectionEnabled = value;
            if (!m_SelectionEnabled) ClearSelection();
        }
    } 
}

protected override void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    // Does not prevent Cell edit
    if (!m_SelectionEnabled) ClearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. One problem noticed in this approach. Grid rows will be selected while mouse dragging. So I tried out `ClearSelection()` instead of setting `CurrentCell = null` in above code. This met all my requirement.

Please share your valuable comments in using `ClearSelection()` method. Is this a proper approach?

Comment: As you can see in the [.Net Source Code about CurrentCell](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2176), when you set this Property to `null`, it calls `ClearSelection()`, but testing slightly different conditions first, e.g., that the current `RowIndex` matches the `CurrentCell.Y` value. Calling `ClearSelection()` prevents the selection while dragging, but it allows editing. That's why I asked you about your specific requirements and specific context. -- I'll add a note about the difference.

Comment: Note that with `CurrentCell = null` you can highlight Rows only when `MultiSelect = true`, with `MultiSelect = false`, there's no highlight.